# Xcode 8.1 images are not shown

Tags: uistoryboard, ios10, xcode8

Images are not shown in Xcode 8.1 in UIImageView or any control in which we can show images. 
I have @3x set of images added. Please help me out how to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Please post code.

Comment: @shallowThought: I am using that in Storyboard .I have uploaded the screenshot of storyboard.

Comment: I am also using XCode 8.1 and its working fine. Try to quit the XCode and relaunch it then remove the ImageView and add a ImageView from Object Library freshly and try assigning the image for it.

Answer (score 0):

**using Xcode 8.2.1**

I ran into the same issue. You need to add images for all three sizes (1x, 2x, 3x), because although the eventual build uses whatever size alternative it can find, the storyboard requires the image size for the device you've selected when Xcode asked you to choose one for "show as".

If you want to use the same image for all sizes, drag the same file in all three size containers in Assets.xcassets, example below.

[image: all three image sizes]